# Android mpchart - barchart add grid line and interlaced Colours

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have questions about mpchart.

I made a barchart by Mpchart in Android

I almost made it but can't add grid and background

does any one help me?

[image]

(this is not android chart. I made by excel... can i do this?)

anywhere can I make like it by mpchart in android?

I really want to your help

**edited :**  'grid' means grid line. it means line that forms part of a grid. 
'background' mean interlaced colour. in my image, it is Gray

**here's my code**

```
    private fun drawBarChart(data: ArrayList<BarEntry>) {
        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(data, null).apply {
            this.setDrawIcons(false)
            gradientColors = barGradient()
            setDrawValues(false)
        }
        val barData = BarData(barDataSet).apply {
            this.setDrawValues(false)
            this.barWidth = 0.2f
        }
        reportHistoryInjuryBarChart.apply {
            customBarChartRenderer.setRadius(10)
            this.renderer = customBarChartRenderer
            description.isEnabled = false
            setTouchEnabled(false)
            setDrawValueAboveBar(true)
            setDrawBarShadow(false)
            setDrawGridBackground(false)
            setFitBars(true)
            axisLeft.apply {
                setDrawZeroLine(true)
                setDrawLabels(false)
                setDrawAxisLine(false)
                setDrawGridLines(true)
                zeroLineWidth = 0.5f
                axisMaximum = 100f
                axisMinimum = 0f

            }
            axisRight.apply {
                setDrawZeroLine(false)
                setDrawLabels(false)
                setDrawAxisLine(false)
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                axisMaximum = 100f
                axisMinimum = 0f
            }
            xAxis.apply {
                position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                setDrawAxisLine(false)
                setDrawLabels(true)
                labelCount = 3
                granularity = 1f
                valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(eachPart.date)
                this.axisLineColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            }
            legend.apply {
                isEnabled = false
            }
            this.data = barData
            invalidate()
        }
```

Comment: What does grid means in chart?

Comment: i mean grid line of chart